# How to make editbox to accept only alphabets in Pascal

Tags: delphi, pascal

```
procedure Tform1.edtFnameKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: char);
begin
if not(Key IN ['0'..'9', #8, #9, #13, #27, #127]) then
   begin



   end
else showmessage('Must contain alphabets only')
end;
```

I have tried using edittextbox's keypress procedure but it did not work.

Comment: Don't do it this way. Let the user type whatever they like, and validate at the point of use.

Comment: Agreed with David.  An example of this pattern here : http://stackoverflow.com/q/32005290/327083

Comment: You were almost there. I wonder what stopped you from accomplishing the task?

Comment: You don't want to allow non-English letters? For example, do you want the user to be able to type `hjälpvinkelmetoden` and `smörgåsbord`?

Answer (score 2):

Other than trying to tell Pascal what not to accept, you should tell it what only to accept. Also you should cancel the input out by `Key := #0` if it doesn't meet your criteria.

```
if not (Key in ['A'..'Z', 'a'..'z']) then
begin

  Key := #0;   //Cancel the input
  ShowMessage('Must contain alphabets only');

end;
```

Comment: how do i use edtfname.text to check if it contain numbers

Comment: You can run the string through a loop and see if each character doesn't meet your criteria.

Comment: You need to have `onChange` event too in collaboration with `onKeyPress` to impose more complete filtering.

Comment: I used `ShowMessage` to make the OP more familiar with the new information.

Comment: Gentlemen, please stay on topic. You just cannot debate over accessibility issues of every homework assignment.

Comment: @FreeConsulting We're all on topic apart from you

Comment: Please include a picture of an 'alphabat'.