# Delphi- Make a EditBox to accept only numbers lessthan or equal to(<=) 12 on Keypress event

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have an Edit box and am trying to make it to only accept numbers from 0 to 12. I wrote an onExit handler like this:

```
procedure TfrmCourse.edtDurationExit(Sender: TObject);
begin
     if not string.IsNullOrEmpty(edtDuration.Text) then
          begin
            if StrToInt(edtDuration.Text) > 12 then
            begin
              edtDuration.Clear;
              edtDuration.SetFocus;
            end;
          end;
end;
```

... but I want to check this *while typing*. The TEdit should only accept numeric input and warn when the value is > 12.

ANSWER that i propose for this question is

**FINAL ANSWER**

```
procedure TfrmCourse.edtDurationKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
var
  sTextvalue: string;
begin
  if Sender = edtDuration then
  begin
    if (Key = FormatSettings.DecimalSeparator) AND
      (pos(FormatSettings.DecimalSeparator, edtDuration.Text) <> 0) then
      Key := #0;

    if (charInSet(Key, ['0' .. '9'])) then
    begin
      sTextvalue := TEdit(Sender).Text + Key;
      if sTextvalue <> '' then
      begin
        if ((StrToFloat(sTextvalue) > 12) and (Key <> #8)) then
          Key := #0;
      end;
    end
  end;
end;
```

Comment: A TMaskEdit control can limit the input to two digits, but to get a valid range, you have to do your own derived control.

Comment: This is a handler called *edtDurationExit* but you check *edtDays* values... Rename the event if it is the edtDays.OnExit handler.

Comment: Use one of the OnKey... events.

Comment: `TSpinEdit` control fulfills most of your requirements, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conversion function `StrToInt()` raises an `EConvertError` if the entered characters are not numeric. You can deal with this by setting `TEdit.NumbersOnly` property. I suggest to use `TryStrToInt()` function instead (or in addition). Although you said that you want to check *while typing* I also suggest using the `OnChange` event, because it also catches erroneous input by pasting from clipboard.

```
procedure TForm5.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
  ed: TEdit;
  v: integer;
begin
  ed := Sender as TEdit;
  v := 0;
  if (ed.Text <> '') and
    (not TryStrToInt(ed.Text, v) or (v < 0) or (v > 12)) then
  begin
    ed.Color := $C080FF;
    errLabel.Caption := 'Only numbers 0 - 12 allowed';
    Exit;
  end
  else
  begin
    ed.Color := clWindow;
    errLabel.Caption := '';
  end;
end;
```

The `errLabel` is a label near the edit box that gives the user indication of erroneous entry.

Comment: `ShowMessage` is a terrible option in a `Change` handler - this is awfully frustrating to a user.  Better to give them non-modal feedback that the entry is invalid.  Showing a message is fine when they need to commit the values or proceed with some operation that depends on complete validation of the input but not while they're trying to type things in.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/32008542/327083  It's also a questionable idea to change the contents of the control in its own `Change` handler.

Comment: I used to color Textboxes red-ish on erroneous input and would only display messageboxes on exiting them (which also has the benefit of forcing the focus back to it). Alternative approaches are to display errors in a TStatusBar, or using Hints for that.

Comment: @J... You are right about the message box and also regarding doing a change in the OnChange handler as a principle. I was too hectic to scratch it together. Funny (or not) how I already forgot about the "1 to 49" question and your answer which I even read in detail since I UV'ed it. I will remove my answer shortly, as soon as you ack this comment.

Comment: @TomBrunberg I wouldn't think you should remove it - the idea is fine, just that modal feedback is maybe less good than non-modal.

Comment: @J... Thanks for encourageing to leave it anyway. I replaced the message box with a label and color combination, and removed the reverting of the text.